# How to drain the window after a Flink join using coGroup()?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, outer-join, stream-processing

I'd like to join data coming in from two Kafka topics ("left" and "right").

Matching records are to be joined using an ID, but if a "left" or a "right" record is missing, the other one should be passed downstream after a certain timeout. Therefore I have chosen to use the `coGroup` function.

This works, but there is one problem: If there is no message at all, there is always at least one record which stays in an internal buffer for good. It gets pushed out when new messages arrive. Otherwise it is stuck.

The expected behaviour is that all records should be pushed out after the configured idle timeout has been reached.

Some information which might be relevant

- Flink 1.14.4
- The Flink parallelism is set to 8, so is the number of partitions in both Kafka topics.
- Flink checkpointing is enabled
- Event-time processing is to be used
- Lombok is used: So `val` is like `final var`

Some code snippets:

### Relevant join settings

```
public static final int AUTO_WATERMARK_INTERVAL_MS = 500;

public static final Duration SOURCE_MAX_OUT_OF_ORDERNESS = Duration.ofMillis(4000);
public static final Duration SOURCE_IDLE_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMillis(1000);

public static final Duration TRANSFORMATION_MAX_OUT_OF_ORDERNESS = Duration.ofMillis(5000);
public static final Duration TRANSFORMATION_IDLE_TIMEOUT = Duration.ofMillis(1000);

public static final Time JOIN_WINDOW_SIZE = Time.milliseconds(1500);
```

### Create `KafkaSource`

```
private static KafkaSource<JoinRecord> createKafkaSource(Config config, String topic) {
    val properties = KafkaConfigUtils.createConsumerConfig(config);

    val deserializationSchema = new KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema<JoinRecord>() {
        @Override
        public void deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record, Collector<JoinRecord> out) {
            val m = JsonUtils.deserialize(record.value(), JoinRecord.class);

            val copy = m.toBuilder()
                    .partition(record.partition())
                    .build();

            out.collect(copy);
        }

        @Override
        public TypeInformation<JoinRecord> getProducedType() {
            return TypeInformation.of(JoinRecord.class);
        }
    };

    return KafkaSource.<JoinRecord>builder()
            .setProperties(properties)
            .setBootstrapServers(config.kafkaBootstrapServers)
            .setTopics(topic)
            .setGroupId(config.kafkaInputGroupIdPrefix + "-" + String.join("_", topic))
            .setDeserializer(deserializationSchema)
            .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
            .build();
}
```

### Create `DataStreamSource`

Then the `DataStreamSource` is built on top of the `KafkaSource`:

- Configure "max out of orderness"
- Configure "idleness"
- Extract timestamp from record, to be used for event time processing

```java
private static DataStreamSource<JoinRecord> createLeftSource(Config config,
                                                             StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
    val leftKafkaSource = createLeftKafkaSource(config);

    val leftWms = WatermarkStrategy
            .<JoinRecord>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(SOURCE_MAX_OUT_OF_ORDERNESS)
            .withIdleness(SOURCE_IDLE_TIMEOUT)
            .withTimestampAssigner((joinRecord, __) -> joinRecord.timestamp.toEpochSecond() * 1000L);

    return env.fromSource(leftKafkaSource, leftWms, "left-kafka-source");
}
```

### Use `keyBy`

The *keyed sources* are created on top of the `DataSource` instances like this:

- Again configure "out of orderness" and "idleness"
- Again extract timestamp

  ```
   val leftWms = WatermarkStrategy
           .<JoinRecord>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(TRANSFORMATION_MAX_OUT_OF_ORDERNESS)
           .withIdleness(TRANSFORMATION_IDLE_TIMEOUT)
           .withTimestampAssigner((joinRecord, __) -> {
               if (VERBOSE_JOIN)
                   log.info("Left : " + joinRecord);
               return joinRecord.timestamp.toEpochSecond() * 1000L;
           });

   val leftKeyedSource = leftSource
           .keyBy(jr -> jr.id)
           .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(leftWms)
           .name("left-keyed-source");
  ```

### Join using `coGroup`

The join then combines the left and the right *keyed sources*

```
    val joinedStream = leftKeyedSource
            .coGroup(rightKeyedSource)
            .where(left -> left.id)
            .equalTo(right -> right.id)
            .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(JOIN_WINDOW_SIZE))
            .apply(new CoGroupFunction<JoinRecord, JoinRecord, JoinRecord>() {
                       @Override
                       public void coGroup(Iterable<JoinRecord> leftRecords, 
                                           Iterable<JoinRecord> rightRecords,
                                           Collector<JoinRecord> out) {
                           // Transform
                           val result = ...;

                           out.collect(result);
                       }
```

### Write stream to console

The resulting `joinedStream` is written to the console:

```
    val consoleSink = new PrintSinkFunction<JoinRecord>();
    joinedStream.addSink(consoleSink);
```

- How can I configure this join operation, so that all records are pushed downstream after the configured idle timeout?
- If it can't be done this way: Is there another option?

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected behavior. `withIdleness` doesn't try to handle the case where all streams are idle. It only helps in cases where there are still events flowing from at least one source partition/shard/split.

To get the behavior you desire (in the context of a continuous streaming job), you'll have to implement a custom watermark strategy that advances the watermark based on a processing time timer. [Here's an implementation that uses the legacy watermark API.](https://github.com/aljoscha/flink/blob/6e4419e550caa0e5b162bc0d2ccc43f6b0b3860f/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/timestamps/ProcessingTimeTrailingBoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor.java)

On the other hand, if the job is complete and you just want to drain the final results before shutting it down, you can use the `--drain` option when you stop the job. Or if you use bounded sources this will happen automatically.

Comment: Thank you, David. It is a continuous streaming job. Is there a replacement for the deprecated `AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks` interface? As for an alternative: What about a single Kafka source to listen on both topics (or `union()`) , and then use a custom stateful join function for `process()` which uses `onTimer` to flush the buffer? All of these options seem quite complex, am I doing something so exotic?